# Natural Naming Scheme for a dynamic set of members

Tags: python, dynamic

The desire is for the user to instantiate a class that represents the transeint along with automatic access to a member item for each variable being represented (up to 200 variables). The set of variable class instances would be dynamic based on file based input data and the desire is to use the file provided variable names to create a collection of these variable instances that are accessible with a natural naming scheme. Effectively, the variable class hides the details of where the data is stored and the indepedent variable (ie, time) is stored. The following pseudo code expresses random lines that the end user may express. In some cases, the post processing may be much more extensive.

```
tran1 = CTransient('TranData', ...)
Padj = tran1.pressPipe1 + 10  # add 10 bar to a pressure for conservatism
Tsat = TsatRoutine( tran1.tempPipe1 )
MyPlotRoutine( tran1.tempPipe1, tran1.tempPipe2 )
```

where pressPipeX and tempPipeX names defined in the input data files and the corresponding numpy data vectors are specified in the 'TranData' file input file and are instances of a CVariable class.

Help on how to dynamically build the set of instances that represent the transient variables such that they can be accessed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description of what you're trying to do isn't entirely clear, but automatically naming variables something1, something2, etc. are generally a bad idea. Use a list instead:

```
transientvariables = []
transientvariables.append(makenewtransientvariable())
# ...
for tv in transientvariables:
    print tv
```

**Edit:** OK, I think I see what you're getting at, although your explanation still isn't exactly easy to read. You have a collection of pipes, with a time series of temperature and pressure recorded for each one, right?

The easiest way would be to use a dictionary:

```
transients["tempPipe1"]
```

Or nested dictionaries:

```
transients["temp"]["Pipe1"]
```

Or you could override your class' `__getattr__` method, so that it looks in a dictionary, and you can do:

```
transients.tempPipe1
```

**Edit 2:** Overriding `__getattr__` would look a bit like this:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name in self.varMap:
        return self.varMap[name]
    raise AttributeError
```

Comment: Thank your feedback which I follow; but, I have expanded to better describe the intention.

Comment: Thx. Sorry it's not clear. Imagine hundreds of data sets with each containing hundreds of variables. At runtime the input data has to be constructed so that a call to tran.tempParam so that the tempParam object can use __getattr__ to provide a numpy array. The class object for which tempParam is instantiated hides the details on numpy array access. The ? is how should a large number of class members be dynamically instantiated given definition provided as part of the trans input data. Perhaps simply dynamically building instantation code and running an exec in the constructor is acceptable.

Comment: @tnt: Are your variables stored in a numpy array? Or is each variable a numpy array? I *think* that by "class members", you mean attributes of an instance. If so, I wouldn't make them attributes at all. Make a dictionary mapping the names to the objects, and then override `__getattr__` to do a dictionary lookup.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for driving your point home. The numpy arrays are actually stored in an hdf file (PyTables) and the variable class instance will know where they are stored and the class  override for __getattr__ can perform the "lookup" and return the numpy array. So, your suggestion would be to have a map to these object instances along with the __getattr__ override. It is a bit more verbose for the end user than what I had invisioned (tran.varMap["tempVar1"] instead of tran.tempVar1 for example). But, I am now leaning towards your more explicit and "Pythonic" approach.

Comment: @tnt: Well, you can use `__getattr__` to hide that detail, if you like. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @Thomas K got to what I need despite my confusion of how     __getattr__ works. With this new understanding, the original post has been cleaned up.